# Magento admin is only showing 2 custom attributes on product admin page, new attributes I've created don't display

Tags: magento, attributes, product, admin

A few months ago when I first started setting up this Magento 2 site I created the custom product attributes "size" and "style" in Magento Admin-- everything worked fine and whenever I am setting up any product, dropdowns for Size and Style show up in the Attributes section of Catalog/Products.

Now I have created three more custom attributes in Magento Admin that I want to use, and I have configured them the exact same way as my original two. However, dropdowns for these new attributes are not showing up in the Attributes section of Catalog/Products.

I have flushed the Magento cache and reindexed with no success. Does Magento only allow 2 custom attributes for products, or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the custom attribute by code with your module or create it with Magento Admin?

For Magento Admin, please share the steps.

Please share the whole code which you write to create the attribute. Please confirm that follow the right steps:

Below code that you use to create a custom drop-down attribute.

```
 /* Product Custom Multi Select Option */
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'custom_cms_pages');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'custom_cms_pages',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Custom CMS Pages',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 30,
                'source' => \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\CMSPageList::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'group' => 'custom_content_hide',
            ]
        );
```